# How are network site user profiles linked?

Tags: discussion, network-profile, database-design

This is a technical question aimed at the **Stack Exchange developers**

I'm wondering about the database storage of each Stack Exchange site. Is each site stored in it's own database?

Mainly however, **how do the multiple Stack Exchange websites link a users profile together?**

It seems like each Stack Exchange website is a separate database, that then has a master database which records a list of all the sites a users profile is active on. This would seem to allow for a user to easily sign up to one site, with the Stack Exchange network knowing which other sites a user is signed up on.